# How can I set 2 different color in Tab Bar tint color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar with image and title. How can I set selected tab bar item image to gradient color?

**Current**

[image]

**Expected Result and original selected image**

[image]

What I did so far:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:ThemeBlueColor];
}
```

Is there any method to set the gradient color for `[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:ThemeBlueColor];`? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: you don't set tint colour to image property of tabbar button. you should set selected image and deselect image to tabbar button and title colour accordingly @Henry

Comment: Hi @vikramsingh mind to share some sample code on it? Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do have changed tabbar button properties like title colour and selected and deselected image with objective c code and provided *** converted code with Swiftify***.

call this method in your first ViewController's viewDidLoad() of tabBarController and you are good to go

please have a look - :

```
//  Converted with Swiftify v1.0.6472 - https://objectivec2swift.com/
func setTabBarSelectedDeselectedIconsAndTitleColor() {
    let recentItem = tabBarController?.tabBar.items[0] as? UITabBarItem
    recentItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 91.0 / 255.0, green: 46.0 / 255.0, blue: 224.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)], for: .normal)
    recentItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 91.0 / 255.0, green: 46.0 / 255.0, blue: 224.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)], for: .selected)
    recentItem?.image = UIImage(named: "home_unselect_icon.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    recentItem?.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "home_select_icon.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    recentItem = tabBarController?.tabBar.items[1]
    recentItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 91.0 / 255.0, green: 46.0 / 255.0, blue: 224.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)], for: .normal)
    recentItem.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 91.0 / 255.0, green: 46.0 / 255.0, blue: 224.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)], for: .selected)
    recentItem.image = UIImage(named: "kid_location_unselect_icon.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    recentItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "kid_location_select_icon.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
}
```

***similar objective-c equivalent -:***

```
-(void)setTabBarSelectedDeselectedIconsAndTitleColor{
    UITabBarItem *recentItem = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[0];
    [recentItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:91.0f/255.0f green:46.0f/255.0f blue:224.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [recentItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:91.0f/255.0f green:46.0f/255.0f blue:224.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    recentItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_unselect_icon.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    recentItem.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_select_icon.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    recentItem = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[1];
    [recentItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:91.0f/255.0f green:46.0f/255.0f blue:224.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [recentItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:91.0f/255.0f green:46.0f/255.0f blue:224.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    recentItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"kid_location_unselect_icon.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    recentItem.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"kid_location_select_icon.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vikram, posible to share objective-c code? I using obj-c now.

Comment: I believe you are able to set images to tabbar button!

Comment: Great and thanks alot dude @vikram! It works after I added `imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` in my code!

Answer (score 0):

You take assets of image in gradient color and for selected image just set that image or in unselected respectively.

Comment: Hi @Anil, is there any method to set it programmatically?